# How to migrate firebase anonymous user to authenticated user in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

In my app, user can login as guest user. I want to authenticate the guest user with email & password, or with google. The user id should remain the same after authentication. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upgrade an anonymous account to an account with credentials, you create a new account with the sign-in method that you want to use, and then [link the anonymous account and that new account together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) as shown in the Firebase documentation.

So in Flutter you'd use the relevant auth provider's `getCredential` method (e.g. [Facebook](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FacebookAuthProvider/getCredential.html) or [Google](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/GoogleAuthProvider/getCredential.html)) and then call [`linkWithCredential`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/linkWithCredential.html) on the anonymous user object.

Comment: What about email-password authentication? How to get authCredential from email-password sign up?

Comment: I highly recommend browsing the documentation links I already, because it should be quite easy to find the other providers from that. Here's the way to get credentials from email+password signin: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/EmailAuthProvider/getCredential.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you please expand? Now that I've connected them, the anonymous user does not contain the authenticated user's email/displayName/photoUrl. Calling `linkWithCredential` also does not trigger `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` so there's no visible change in the UI that user has linked their account. I just want the `AuthResult` user returned from `linkWithCredential` to be the new user in the stream. I can ask a new question if you'd like.

Comment: Sounds like a new (although related) question to me, so please post as such inded. That'd also give others a chance to answer.